# Generate image from a swf file issue

Tags: php, ffmpeg, flash

I am trying to generate first frame of a swf as a `thumbnail` image so the user can see it before they open the `swf` file.

1.Using `FFMpeg`

```
ffmpeg -i movie.swf -f image2 -vcodec png movie%d.png
```

using command line with `ffmpeg` to generate images. the above command will 
give me errors saying

```
[swf @ 0x17937a0] Compressed SWF format not supported
```

2.Using `swftools`

Their website provide a `tar` file to download however, I only have the `command line` access in the server so I won't be able to install the tools.

I need to use server side technology because I have hundreds of swf files.

Answer (score 1):

```
p7zip e movie.swf
ffmpeg -i movie~.swf movie.png
```

Most SWF files are compressed to save space, similar to a `.tar.gz` or `.zip`. So before you can use it with FFmpeg, you need to extract or decompress the file.

`p7zip` is a
[command line program](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net)
that can extract SWF.